# poloniex futures api php

Tags: php, curl

I am unable to POST data to Poloniex Futures API. While the GET works fine.

The POST returns 400005 [msg] => Invalid PF-API-SIGN

Here is the Code for config.php

```
global $baseurl;
$baseurl = "https://futures-api.poloniex.com";

global $api_key;
$api_key = "XXXXX";

global $api_secret;
$api_secret = "XXXXX";

global $api_passphrase;
$api_passphrase = "XXXXXX";


function signature($request_path = '', $body = '', $timestamp = false, $method = 'POST') {
        

          $body = is_array($body) ? json_encode($body) : $body; // Body must be in json format

          $timestamp = $timestamp ? $timestamp : time() * 1000;

        $what = $timestamp . $method . $request_path . $body;

          return base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $what, $api_secret, true));
 }
```

Working code to get Ticket Data
Code for ticker.php

```
include_once "config.php";


$endpoint = "/api/v1/position?symbol=BTCUSDTPERP";
$url = "https://futures-api.poloniex.com".$endpoint;
$sigs = signature($endpoint,'',true,"GET");
$now = time() * 1000;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = [
        "PF-API-SIGN: $sigs",
        "PF-API-TIMESTAMP: $now",
        "PF-API-KEY: $api_key",
        "PF-API-PASSPHRASE: $api_passphrase"
    ];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$return_data = json_decode($server_output ,true);
print_r($return_data );
```

Here is what I have tried for Add Margin Manually
POST /api/v1/position/margin/deposit-margin

Code for post_data.php

```
include_once "config.php";
$endpoint = "/api/v1/position/margin/deposit-margin";
$url = "https://futures-api.poloniex.com".$endpoint;
$now = time() * 1000;

$vars_margin = ["symbol"=>"BTCUSDTPERP","margin"=>1,"bizNo"=>"1112222"];
$vars_margin = json_encode($vars_margin);
$vars_margin_post_fields  = "symbol=BTCUSDTPERP&margin=1&bizNo=1112222";

$sigs = signature($endpoint,$vars_margin,true,"POST");


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$vars_margin_post_fields);  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = [
        "PF-API-SIGN: $sigs",
        "PF-API-TIMESTAMP: $now",
        "PF-API-KEY: $api_key",
        "PF-API-PASSPHRASE: $api_passphrase"
    ];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$return_data = json_decode($server_output ,true);
print_r($return_data );
```

Really not sure why the post method always says
Array ( [code] => 400005 [msg] => Invalid PF-API-SIGN )

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Post fields should match what was signed, the json_encoded value.

So try this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars_margin);
```

and be sure to add a header to indicate that the POST data is json encoded:

```
    ...
    "PF-API-PASSPHRASE: $api_passphrase",
    "content-type: application/json"
];
```